# Is there a Python dunder method for append?

Tags: python

I have a class which contains a list

```
class Initialise():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
```

I want to instantiate this class and then add items to the list by referencing the list name, but I would like to keep that internal to the class (it would also make my code a bit shorter and clearer).

```
# What I have to do
list_of_items = Initialise()
list_of_items.items.append(...)

# What I would like to do
list_of_items.append(...)
```

I've tried googling for a solution, but can't seem to find anything. Simply adding an append dunder method doesn't work (no surprise there!).

So, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to override / implement a dunder method? Why not just implement `append()`? Or, if this object "is" a list, just inherit from `list`?

Comment: Do you consider to subclass list?Also, what about other methods , do you want to implement e.g. extend() or indexing/slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `append` method:

```
class Initialise:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def append(self, value): 
        self.items.append(value)

list_of_items = Initialise()
list_of_items.append(...)
```

There's nothing special about this method.

Comment: If doing that *(just a pass though call)*, I'd change `value` to `*args, **kwargs`

Comment: @MatBailie why? [Lists `append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) only has one argument.

Comment: Forward Compatibility and standard practice.

Comment: @MatBailie Fair point. I think it depends on the actual use case. I think in this particular case using `value` explicitly is better in case OP would want to manipulate it, it's easier for the code-reader and IDE user.

Comment: @MatBailie if it is implemented that way, how would appending to the list work? That will just leave room for so much confusion rather than a straight answer for the OP.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon It would work identically to normal `update()` it just passes through all positional and keywork arguments. It's the standard syntax for a method wrapping around another method.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon You'd just use `self.items.append(*args, **kwargs)`. But I agree that it can be confusing and don't see a point in doing this in this situation.